# I am new to firebase but have been using java script for a while but i don't understand what snap => does and why its used

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I started using firebase and I came across the `snap =>` when passing value:

```
var rh = document.getElementById('rh'); 
var dbref = firebase.database().ref('text') 
dbref.on('value', snap => rh.innerText = snap.val())
```

I would like to understand what it does and what is the use of it.

Comment: Can you show an example? Sounds like https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions.

Comment: var rh = document.getElementById('rh');
var dbref = firebase.database().ref('text')

dbref.on('value', snap => rh.innerText = snap.val())

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just simple syntax for a function. Instead of:

```
function f(snap) {
    return "hello world";
}
const c = f;
```

You can write the following to make it easier to read:

```
const c = snap => return "hello world";
```

Now `c` is a constant that holds the function above.

Comment: Glad to help out!